# Can I publish an open graph song with a url to our product page for the album

Tags: facebook-opengraph, meta-tags, audio-player, url-link

It seems that Facebook will not allow a music:song to have a og:url that is useful. As a result the link that shows up in a users timeline is dead.

I have even tried making the og:url be equal to the object page(shown below). Basically it is a failing page when called.
Is this due to the whitelist issue?

Or am I missing something in the documentation? How can I make that link that is in the timeline useful? "User listened to track on our Radio." track needs to be a valid link or not shown as a link. User,track and Radio are all made into links by default. Only the track is bad. It links to the facebook_object_page.

```
<meta property="fb:app_id"       content="OurId" /> 
<meta property="og:type"         content="music.song" /> 
<meta property="og:url"          content="https://mysite/facebook_object_page.php?artist=<?php echo $_GET['artist'];?>&product_id=<?php echo $_POST['product_id']; ?>" /> 
<meta property="og:title"        content="<?php echo $_GET['artist'];?>" /> 
<meta property="og:image"        content="http://mysite/images/product_images/products_150/<?php echo $_POST['product_id'];?>.jpg" />
```

Comment: Please define “dead” and “bad”. What are the exact URLs you are using, and how is what gets linked on Facebook different?

Comment: Yeah, the URL needs to be a URL with the metadaa describing the song, but you can host other content there too or redirect other (non-facebook-crawler) traffic elsewhere after it lands on your site

Comment: The url I have been trying is the url to the object page which takes parameters that set the metadata. For some reason it is not possible to view that page. Browser hangs but the open graph publishes correctly to the timeline.

Comment: can I do a meta redirect after one second? Will Facebook have scraped or will it think it needs to follow the redirect?

Comment: Even in the debugger the facebook scraper sees the page extracts the meta and then chopps off the second parameter. Then clicking the link takes me to a page not found.